# Modal viewController

Tags: iphone

My Question is what is the difference between a ViewController and a Modal ViewController ?

Thanks for your answers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modal view controller is used (usually) to gather information from the user before resuming operation. Basically, the view shown is only dismissed when the user completes a form or something similar. While shown, the modal view does not allow in any way accessing the other views shown, until it's dismissed.

Full details available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html).

Answer (score 2):

No difference, except for the way that they're presented. A modal view controller is any view controller that's presented modally, using -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:].